# Add border around Div HTML component in Dash (Python)

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am simply trying to add a border around a html.Div component in Dash using Python. I have tried something like:

```
    html.Div(children=[...], style={"border":"2px")
```

or

```
    html.Div(children=[...], style={"border":{"width":"2px", "color":"black"})
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Can someone help on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```py
html.Div(children=[...], style={"border":"2px black solid"})
```

> The [border property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) is a shorthand property for the following individual border properties:
>       border-width
>       border-style (required)
>       border-color

**Better way** is to use `css classes`

```py
html.Div(children=[...], className='divBorder')
```

then add a css class

```
.divBorder{
 border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: in your code you have missing `}` at end and `color borderStyle` from value. if  double braces doesn't work, then try with single brace.

Comment: yea that was just a typo. but your suggestion works, thank you